# Python - Define class method outside class - Can't start method name with underscore

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm defining a class method outside of the class and in a different module, but I am unable to start the name of the function with an underscore. I was wondering why that is, and if anyone can suggest a good naming convention.

My current approach is below. My intent is that the underscores helps to remember it is intended for a class method,

```
######
# main.py
######
class MyClass:
   method = _MyClass_fcn

######
# helper.py
######
def _MyClass_fcn():
   # definition
```

Comment: Why would u want to define a class method outside the class? secondly, ur missing def keyword if that is a function

Comment: It's a large file, so just helping to maintain. Good eye, fixed now.

Comment: How, exactly, did you import the function from helper.py?  If it was via `from helper import *`, note that this normally skips names starting with an underscore, on the grounds that such names generally indicate things that are private.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I'm doing it. Makes sense, thanks. Any way to override that?

Comment: Other people have given you enough information to do what you want, but you should know that "class method" usually means a method defined in the `class` block and decorated with `@classmethod`. Your method here would work more like a "static method."

Answer (score 0):

if both your files are in the same folder. follow the below code

Helper.py

```
 def _MyClass_fcn():
     return 'HellNo'
 def hello():
    return 'hello'
```

Main.py

```
from helper import _MyClass_fcn
from helper import * # if you have more than one function in that file

class MyClass:
    method = _MyClass_fcn()
    print(method)


q = MyClass()
```

Comment: This does work, but becomes inconvenient for a class with many methods.